# I have LOTS of TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS and TAP-Windows Adapter V9

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter

What are these, and what are they used for; how do I get rid of this? Because I haven't got OpenVPN or any other VPN-client installed on my computer (to my knowledge).

I am not sure but I thing this makes my computer "not connect to the Internet as fast as it should" on start-up.
Provided image displays my annoyance. (It's Norwegian)

[image: Network adapters]

Comment: Looks like you have LogMeIn Hamachi installed, which is technically VPN software.  I'm guessing those adapters are used by Hamachi . . .

Comment: Hamachi hasn't been anything but trouble for me though; I uninstalled it.

Comment: Have had this same issue for months now and can't figure it out.  Do not have Hamachi installed, must be some other application.  Arghhhh.

Comment: I acrually got rid of all the adapters, dont really know how, bur i deactivated most of them. And suddenly I didn't have any more

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know that this question is old, but maybe it can help other people that come across with this same question. I found a solution, though it is not a permanent solution, the TAP adapters will keep coming while you keep a KMS activator or a VPN client of sorts running, which can keep installing these adapters over and over (the reason for that I don't really know, bad programmers maybe? :P ).

Anyways, here's what you can do:

- Download OpenVPN: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html
- Uncheck all the boxes except the TAP Adapter utility and install.
- Open your Notepad with admin privileges and open the file C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin\deltapall.bat
- Replace "remove tap0901" for "remove tapoas"
- Save the script in the same folder with the name 'deltapall2.bat' (or any name you would like to give to it, doesn't matter, as long the extension is bat)
- Open your command prompt with admin privileges.
- cd "c:\program files\tap-windows\bin"
- deltapall and wait for it finish
- deltapall2 and wait for it to finish
- Go to your Devices Manager and you will see that all TAP adapters are removed.
- Restart your PC and you are ready to go!

To prevent a KMS tool to install these TAP adapters again and again and again, go to the Task Scheduler and disable or delete all of the KMS tasks that were created. Though the KMS tool service may create those tasks all over again! So yeah... there is nothing to do about that.
If you are using a KMS tool, I would recommend you to stop using these activators and just support the developers of the software you are using by buying a license! You would avoid all this confusion.

Finally, be advised that if you actually use VPN, you will probably be unable to access it without a TAP Adapter. So if you use VPN you may want to keep your VPN adapter, if it is a TAP adapter, reinstall it running your VPN's install software, or the OpenVPN's one, or using the 'addtap' script included in the same folder as the 'deltapall'.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Typically I'd delete answers that talk about piracy but " I would recommend you to stop using these activators and just support the developers of the software you are using by buying a license! " is awesome advice.

Comment: Thank you! Well, I'm not here to support piracy just wanted to address the issue. Also... a VPN software can cause this issue too (I've seen that on some machines I worked on). I can delete stuff relating to the kms tool if that makes the answer better? Or it is okay to keep like that?

Comment: In context, meh, leave it.

Comment: @axys93 glad you kept it, I've got licensed office products but my VPN went haywire and created a new driver each time I launched it. They then promptly became activated and deactivated every startup, causing me to not be able to use the internet for that entire time (1 to 5 minutes over a few weeks!!!)

Answer (score 6):

Do the following and they will disappear

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> Type in `msinfo32` and press Enter.

Now you will see the following Console Window.

[image: MSinfo32 console]

In the left pane navigate to components ->Network -> Adapter Here you can see all the Network Adapters listed Find the TAP adapters and see the Driver location as shown in the below image

[image: Location of TAP adapter driver]

I have given a sample image as i have already deleted the TAP adapters. Don't delete the Microsoft Adapters. Find the Tap adapters location in listed adapters & go to the location for example: "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\TAP.sys" and delete them.

After this Just Go to device Management and uninstall the TAP adapters under Network Adapters.

Note: While uninstalling tick the option "Delete the Driver" if asked for a prompt.

That's it, you're done.

Comment: When I did this and restarted my computer I still got a new "TAP-Windows Adapter V9"

Comment: @nibrobb oh you got the V9, it's a special one lol

Answer (score 4):

Do you use **Auto KMS** for Licencing Microsoft products?

Well I had the same problem 2 weeks ago. It seem recently i installed a copy of Office 2013 which came with **Auto KMS** activation. Ever since then a process called **Auto KMS** appeared in my processes.

Anyway I tried to install all the unwanted TAP drivers but it didn't allowed me.Then what I did is **manually uninstalled the drivers from device manager**.

Then opened the file location of the **AutoKMS.exe** from my **task manager** and **deleted it**. Gave a **restart**, and my all drivers were gone forever. As for my Office....**its still working and licensed**.

Comment: I think I was using Auto KMS to activate Microsoft Office products  on the computer in question...

Comment: Of course it still works. Those AutoKMS tools have all those tasks, so they can keep updating your license, since the serial numbers they generate run out after 6 months. But you've probably seen this by now. Those programs are cancer. It causes less pain to just buy Office.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (150 TAP adapters, which significantly slowed down my computer) and in my case the reason was an application called TAP Windows. I don't remember installing that app, so maybe it was installed together with an another software. Anyway uninstalling TAP Windows helped, all tap adapters were gone instantly.

Answer (score 0):

After [downloading OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) `2.5.0` and installing just `"Drivers\TAP-Windows6"` component and then uninstalling it, all TAP devices disappear.