# Way too many network adapters showing up

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter

I was fiddling in Device Manager when I noticed that I have far too many network adapters showing up in Device Manager. I double checked and confirmed in Networking and Sharing Centre under Network Adapters. The attached picture Cleary shows my predicament.

I can account for 3 adapters: (1) Physical adapter on my motherboard, (2) PCI-e Wireless Adapter and (3) a virtual adapter for Hamachi. A lot more is showing up in the list of adapters, and ever so often when I switch my pc on, I find even more adapter showing up. Is a Windows related bug causing the problem since the adapters are called TAP windows adapter? That is just an assumption, I can be completely off.

Hardware Info:
-MSI H97 Gaming 3
-Intel Core i5 4670 @ 3.4GHz
-Gigabyte AMD Radeon R9270X 2GB 256 bit
-8GB Corsair 1600MHz RAM

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Screenshot of device manager would be nice.

Comment: The OAS stuff appears frequently with illegal MS Office activators.

Comment: Yeah I believe the case here might be Hamachi since my office suite is already activated with the education license I received

Comment: Hamachi doesn’t use the TAP-Win32 driver.

Comment: I'll have to investigate further then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely to be related to Hamachi, [TUN/TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) are software virtual network devices.

Whether it would cause any harm to remove them, I do not know, it does seem an extreme amount. There is a very similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/790891/i-have-lots-of-tap-win32-adapter-oas-and-tap-windows-adapter-v9) which did not receive an accepted answer, but may be of further assistance to you.

If I were in your position, I'd uninstall Hamachi and remove them all, then clean install Hamachi again, monitoring the situation as time progressed.

Comment: I see, they seem te say that it can be Hamachi of KMS activator. Will try to remove those and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

TAP is the VPN tunnel used by Hamachi, look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/790891/i-have-lots-of-tap-win32-adapter-oas-and-tap-windows-adapter-v9) for a nearly identical question and answer.

Comment: I see, they seem te say that it can be Hamachi of KMS activator. Will try to remove those and see if it makes a difference.